# how to automatically install a wordpress plugin when activating a wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I want to install a wordpress plugin automatically when I activate a particular wordpress theme and when I deactivate that theme at that time that plugin should also be deactivated. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: http://tgmpluginactivation.com/

Comment: I have tried this but i don't know where exactly to put the code and files provided in it.

Comment: There is a installation guide: http://tgmpluginactivation.com/installation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can activate plugin with http://tgmpluginactivation.com/ site

after download put inside theme and put this code in function.php below is just example plugin code you can change with your's

```
require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php';

add_action( 'tgmpa_register', 'my_theme_register_required_plugins' );
/**
 * Register the required plugins for this theme.
 *
 * In this example, we register two plugins - one included with the TGMPA library
 * and one from the .org repo.
 *
 * The variable passed to tgmpa_register_plugins() should be an array of plugin
 * arrays.
 *
 * This function is hooked into tgmpa_init, which is fired within the
 * TGM_Plugin_Activation class constructor.
 */
function my_theme_register_required_plugins() {

    /**
     * Array of plugin arrays. Required keys are name and slug.
     * If the source is NOT from the .org repo, then source is also required.
     */
    $plugins = array(

        // WooCommerce
        array(
            'name'      => 'Page Builder by SiteOrigin',
            'slug'      => 'siteorigin-panels',
            'required'  => true,
            'force_activation' => true,
            'force_deactivation' => true
        ),

         // WooCommerce
        array(
            'name'      => 'SiteOrigin Widgets Bundle',
            'slug'      => 'so-widgets-bundle',
            'required'  => true,
            'force_activation' => true,
            'force_deactivation' => true
        )


    );

    /**
     * Array of configuration settings. Amend each line as needed.
     * If you want the default strings to be available under your own theme domain,
     * leave the strings uncommented.
     * Some of the strings are added into a sprintf, so see the comments at the
     * end of each line for what each argument will be.
     */
    $config = array(
        'default_path' => '',                      // Default absolute path to pre-packaged plugins.
        'menu'         => 'tgmpa-install-plugins', // Menu slug.
        'has_notices'  => true,                    // Show admin notices or not.
        'dismissable'  => true,                    // If false, a user cannot dismiss the nag message.
        'dismiss_msg'  => '',                      // If 'dismissable' is false, this message will be output at top of nag.
        'is_automatic' => false,                   // Automatically activate plugins after installation or not.
        'message'      => '',                      // Message to output right before the plugins table.
        'strings'      => array(
            'page_title'                      => __( 'Install Required Plugins', 'tgmpa' ),
            'menu_title'                      => __( 'Install Plugins', 'tgmpa' ),
            'installing'                      => __( 'Installing Plugin: %s', 'tgmpa' ), // %s = plugin name.
            'oops'                            => __( 'Something went wrong with the plugin API.', 'tgmpa' ),
            'notice_can_install_required'     => _n_noop( 'This theme requires the following plugin: %1$s.', 'This theme requires the following plugins: %1$s.' ), // %1$s = plugin name(s).
            'notice_can_install_recommended'  => _n_noop( 'This theme recommends the following plugin: %1$s.', 'This theme recommends the following plugins: %1$s.' ), // %1$s = plugin name(s).
            'notice_cannot_install'           => _n_noop( 'Sorry, but you do not have the correct permissions to install the %s plugin. Contact the administrator of this site for help on getting the plugin installed.', 'Sorry, but you do not have the correct permissions to install the %s plugins. Contact the administrator of this site for help on getting the plugins installed.' ), // %1$s = plugin name(s).
            'notice_can_activate_required'    => _n_noop( 'The following required plugin is currently inactive: %1$s.', 'The following required plugins are currently inactive: %1$s.' ), // %1$s = plugin name(s).
            'notice_can_activate_recommended' => _n_noop( 'The following recommended plugin is currently inactive: %1$s.', 'The following recommended plugins are currently inactive: %1$s.' ), // %1$s = plugin name(s).
            'notice_cannot_activate'          => _n_noop( 'Sorry, but you do not have the correct permissions to activate the %s plugin. Contact the administrator of this site for help on getting the plugin activated.', 'Sorry, but you do not have the correct permissions to activate the %s plugins. Contact the administrator of this site for help on getting the plugins activated.' ), // %1$s = plugin name(s).
            'notice_ask_to_update'            => _n_noop( 'The following plugin needs to be updated to its latest version to ensure maximum compatibility with this theme: %1$s.', 'The following plugins need to be updated to their latest version to ensure maximum compatibility with this theme: %1$s.' ), // %1$s = plugin name(s).
            'notice_cannot_update'            => _n_noop( 'Sorry, but you do not have the correct permissions to update the %s plugin. Contact the administrator of this site for help on getting the plugin updated.', 'Sorry, but you do not have the correct permissions to update the %s plugins. Contact the administrator of this site for help on getting the plugins updated.' ), // %1$s = plugin name(s).
            'install_link'                    => _n_noop( 'Begin installing plugin', 'Begin installing plugins' ),
            'activate_link'                   => _n_noop( 'Begin activating plugin', 'Begin activating plugins' ),
            'return'                          => __( 'Return to Required Plugins Installer', 'tgmpa' ),
            'plugin_activated'                => __( 'Plugin activated successfully.', 'tgmpa' ),
            'complete'                        => __( 'All plugins installed and activated successfully. %s', 'tgmpa' ), // %s = dashboard link.
            'nag_type'                        => 'updated' // Determines admin notice type - can only be 'updated', 'update-nag' or 'error'.
        )
    );

    tgmpa( $plugins, $config );

}
```

Comment: my plugin zip file is in wp-content/plugins/profilebuilder.zip and my plugin name is profilebuilder. Then what entries i have to fill in name and slug array.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/profile-builder/
this is the plugin you need so just put this array 
   
     array(
            'name'      => 'Profile Builder - front-end user registration, login and edit profile',
            'slug'      => 'profile-builder',
            'required'  => true,
            'force_activation' => true,
            'force_deactivation' => true
        ),

Comment: and if your source is different then just put this in array this is path to plugin in theme. 

'source'             => get_stylesheet_directory() . '/plugins/profilebuilder.zip', 

example here:- 
http://tgmpluginactivation.com/configuration/

Answer (score 0):

In addition with Corlax's answer, this is a list of services and open sources that might be useful:

- [WP Package Editor](https://wordpress.recuweb.com/)

> WP2E is a service allowing developers to create and manage installation
> packages to deliver and maintain sets of interdependent themes and
> plugins.

- [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/)

> TGM Plugin Activation is a PHP library that allows you to easily
> require or recommend plugins for your WordPress themes (and plugins).

- [WPFavs](https://wpfavs.com/)

> It is a Free WordPress plugin manager and bulk installation tool

- [WP Plugin Dependencies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-dependencies/)

> This meta-plugin allows regular plugins to specify other plugins that
> they depend upon.

- [WP Dependency Installer](https://github.com/afragen/wp-dependency-installer)

> A lightweight class to add to WordPress plugins/themes to
> automatically install plugin dependencies.